# Ionic : Typescript file doesn't load when page is pushed more than twice

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic3

I'm stuck in a development of a mobile game : 
I've made an ionic menu in app.html in order to navigate in every pages of the application. For example, to navigate into the page "Parameters", I've inserted this code in the app.html file :

```
 <ion-col menuClose class="side-col-20" (click)="open('Parameters')">
     <img class="icon-menu" src="../assets/imgs/Parameters.svg" height="40">
     <p class="text-menu">Parameters</p>
 </ion-col>
```

And here is the method open() in the app.component.ts file:

```
@ViewChild(Nav) nav;
open(page:string){
    this.nav.push(page+'Page');
}
```

So through my ionic menu, I tap on Parameters, the page loads and the Javascript code from parameters.ts works correctly. But when I tap more than once on it, the code doesn't work anymore!

What could I do to resolve the problem?

Thanks in advance for your answer.